How can I turn on and off the touchpad with the powershell? (PnpObject X)
These days, I am interested in operating a computer with powerhell.
However, turning off the touch pad and turning it on doesn't work well for some reason.
The Device Manager says this is PS/2 mouse.
The driver is using ElanTech. (from here, i installed for window 10 https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=elan+touchpad)
Enable and Disable with Pnp-Object are not allowed as administrators.
How can I do it with powdershell?
I want control touch-pad with CML

Include your script in question.
